# How to create test class for if-else?

Tags: apex, visualforce

can you give me some guidance about my test class? Well I have a method that has several things and inside it I also have two pairs of IF - Else and I'm not sure how to call this ifs in the test class:

Controller:

```
public List <OpportunityContactRole> getContact(){ 
        if(Contact==null){
            Contact=[SELECT Id,contactId, contactId
                      FROM OpportunityContactRole 
                      WHERE OpportunityId =: idOpp LIMIT 10
                     ];
        }  
        
        ContactSize = Contact.size(); 
        
        for(OpportunityContactRole i: Contact){
            
            if(i.CPF__c==null){
                i.CPF__c=null;  
            }else{
                String formattedCPF = formatacpf(i.CPF__c);
                i.CPF__c=formattedCPF;
            }
            if(i.CPF2__C!=null){
                String formattedCPFproc = formatacpf(i.CPF2__C);
                i.CPF2__C=formattedCPFproc; 
            }
        }
         
               
        return Contact;
    }
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest static void test_Contatos() {
        Test.startTest();

        setupDados(Test.getStandardPricebookId());

        PageReference pageRef = Page.PDFNContato;
        pageRef.getParameters().put('idOpp', String.valueOf(oppPed.Id));
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        DadosContatoss testControllerPDFNtDadosContatos = new DadosDadosContatoss();
        
        testControllerPDFNtDadosContatos.getContact();
        

        Test.stopTest();
    }
```

I looked in [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/pt-BR/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro) the lesson on this subject, but there it only has the if inside the method, so it calls the method and passes a parameter, my case is different how can I solve it?

Comment: For specific advice, it's up to you to create test data to make those if statements relevant. As far as we can see, I'm not sure you created any relevant `OpportunityContactRole` records for the test Opportunity Id. I'm going to guess you haven't as, if you did, you'd get errors trying to reference `CPF__c` without querying it ([row retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000328927&type=1)). Feel free to [edit] and show your test data setup - but, it's all about creating data that would evaluate to true/false for if statements

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, I read the material you indicated, but I'm new to apex, could you give me an example of how to write this data for testing? @KrisGonçalves

Comment: It's hard to help if you don't share what test data you've created (ex. what data does `setupDados` create?) Focus on what the code expects in an org when running and you have to re-create that same data in the test --> Opportunity with OpportunityContactRoles that have certain values in your fields (`CPF__c`)

Answer (score 1):

I would allow `formatacpf(i.CPF__c);` to handle null values. This way you only need one null check, not multiple outside the method.

```
formatacpf(String cpf){
  if (String.isBlank(cpf)){
    return null;
  }
  //do other formatting for non blank cpf
  ...
  return formattedcpf;
}
```

Now your loop can look like:

```
for(OpportunityContactRole i: Contact){
  i.CPF__c  =formatacpf(i.CPF__c);
  i.CPF2__c =formatacpf(i.CPF2__c);
}
```

And because you have separated the null check into a separate function, you can pass ANY string into it. Something that you didn't need to query for.

```
System.assertEquals(null,formatacpf(null));
System.assertEquals('whateveryouareexpecting',formatacpf('nonnullvalue'));
```